# How to bind alt + n to cursor down in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am trying to bind `alt + n` to `send-keys -X cursor down`, but it doesn't work. This is my code right now:

```
bind -T copy-mode M-n send-keys -X cursor-down
bind -T copy-mode M-p send-keys -X cursor-up
```

And I can find it with `:list-keys`

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    M-m                  send-keys -X back-to-indentation
bind-key    -T copy-mode    M-n                  send-keys -X cursor-down
bind-key    -T copy-mode    M-p                  send-keys -X cursor-up
bind-key    -T copy-mode    M-r                  send-keys -X middle-line
bind-key    -T copy-mode    M-v                  send-keys -X page-up
```

What have I missed?

Comment: This (I mean `… cursor-down`, not `… cursor down`) works for me. Please confirm you know what `copy-mode` is and that you want your binding to work specifically in copy mode. Additionally check if Alt+n can get to `tmux`: run a shell without tmux and press Ctrl+v, Alt+n. What do you see? Is it `^[n` maybe?

Comment: Right I think I should not use the binding in copy-mode, as I want to navigate the session list(`<C-b>s` ) with this binding.